# controlling windows machine from raspberry pi 2 over network

Tags: windows-7, raspberry-pi

I am trying to control windows machine connected to same network as raspberry pi 2 from raspberry pi 2 over network any suggestions?I wanted to connect rpi to monitor and leave desktop/laptop in place and control windows machine via vnc viewer or so to control the same.I am using jesse for rpi2,to be connected to tv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need 2 things:

1. A VNC viewer on the PI. These can be found in the repository. Search for VNC and you will find several. Use whatever wokrs best for you.
2. A VNC server on the WIndows machine. RealVNC, UltraVNC or ThightVNC are the most common programs for that.

Just connect the VNC client on the PI to the ip-address of your Windows machine and it should work. (You may have to open port 5900 in the firewall on the Windows machine tough. This isn't always done automatically by the VNC server.)

Comment: Just a note for patrick, you may experience some lag doing this type of a setup. Just keep that in mind, depending on your application

Comment: @Tonny,@Eric F i just tried above and it asked for password i didnt understand so i tried both view only and primary password but it says auth fail

Comment: @pratikshirodkar It depends a bit on which VNC server you are using on the Windows side and how that is configured. Some combinations just don't work as expected. You will have to  play around a it with it to find something that works. Don't overcomplicate things. As a starting point begin without passwords. Than add a VNC primary. Setting BOTH a readonly and a primary password often isn't understood by some clients. Using a combinatron of WIndows security and VNC passwords in many cases only works if the VNC client and the server are from the same supplier.

Comment: @Tonny i use tightvnc server as well as viewer on both rpi and windows machine i am now uninstalling tightvnc on both and resetup both without passwords and take a look at it thanks for suggestion

Comment: @Tonny  i uninstalled and reinstalled it worked was in format xtightvncviewer ip:port then entering standard password Eric F